# How can I make an app to run in fullscreen mode?

Tags: android, fullscreen, trigger.io, forge

I just started using forge, and it rocks (so far) :)

Using trigger.io (Forge) how can I make the app run in fullscreen mode?

I haven't found a way to do so in the documentation.

I know I could manually edit the Android manifest to include

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

But this is not really a feasible solution.

Does trigger.io/forge have a simple way to specify fullscreen apps?

Comment: Why is that not a feasible solution? Just curious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean the ability to effectively hide the status bar?

We have had a couple of requests for this: we're tracking it as a story and aiming to have it complete within the next 3 weeks - I'll keep you updated!

**Update:** since v1.4 Trigger.io has a display module which provides a fullscreen option:
http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/modules/display.html

Comment: Sort of, but Fullscreen is more than just hiding the statusbar programmatically.

Comment: Cool, so we're going in the right direction: what else would you like a Fullscreen mode to entail, beyond hiding the status bar?

Answer (score 0):

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```